# Display HTML form only once in Tomcat Server

Tags: java, html, forms, tomcat, redirect

I have an tomcat server application where in a HTML form is displayed. Once I submit the data the page redirects to another page. In the back-end there is a JAVA program which takes some hours to complete execution. In the mean time if some-one tries to open my HTML page displaying form(First page) from another browser or another tab, it has to redirect automatically to the execution page. Is it possible to do this with Tomcat Server and JAVA? (I am using it on RHEL machine. So please do not post platform specific solutions.)

Comment: looks like you need to store the running status of your background process in a db of file on the server.  Sounds very weird architecture though

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach:

1. Introduce a flag in your server side code to determine whether the multi-hour-job is in progress
2. Whenever backend job is started, set the flag. When job done, reset the flag.
3. Either in your servlet doXXX method or in a servlet filter, check flag if set then redirect, if not then return the form view

Comment: that's what I said (I think).  The flag would need to be external due the tomcat sessions timing out for a few hours process.